# moment().tz() is not giving same .isDST() value as moment.tz()

Tags: timezone, momentjs, dst, moment-timezone

I am facing an issue related to DaylightSaving where time in `America/Los_Angeles` timezone is not adjusting to the Daylight savings when I use `moment(<DateTime>).tz(America/Los_Angeles)`.

```
>> let c = moment('2023-03-12 9:15 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a').tz('America/Los_Angeles', true);
>> c.isDST()
false
```

But when I use moment.tz(), I am getting the right value.

```
>> let c = moment.tz('2023-03-12 9:15 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a', 'America/Los_Angeles');
>> c.isDST()
true
```

Why are they not equal? Which is the right way of doing it? Is there any other problem with the first approach that I should keep in mind while using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is creating a moment based on *local time* of the time zone wherever the code happens to be running.  It's then converting that moment to Pacific time.  The `true` option states to keep the local time while adjusting the time zone and offset only.

The second approach is creating a moment specifically based on Pacific time, without involving the local time zone.

In theory, either version should work.  However, there's [a bug in moment-timezone](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/871) that affects the first approach.  I would use the second only.